# Hook res.render() function in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

is there a way for me to hook `res.render("view")` function right before it executes?

Purpose: I want to hook it and check if the user is on mobile if yes, then edit render page to `res.render("mobile/" + view);` if not on mobile, just render that one.

Comment: `app.use((req, res, next) => { res.render = ...; next() }` at the top of your routes?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts and how can I get the used render "string"? so I can do something like if(isMobile) { res.render = "mobile/" + usedString; }

Comment: Look at the link I cited for duplicate question. It already answers that.